# javascript __proto__: difference between init and object when use kendoComboBox

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-combobox

I trying to use KendoComboBox with the following configuration's dataSource

```
....
 dataSource: {
    type: "json",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: __url,
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    }
},
....
```

And this is what I sent from php:

```
.....
$searchResult[] = array(
    'value' => $object->getCode(),
    'text' => $object->getCode(),
    'pieceDetails' => $object,
    'rowsDetails' => $object->getRows()->toArray(),
);
return new JsonResponse($searchResult);
```

But when I try to showing the selected dataItem after the change event in the console browser

```
change: function (e) {
    var object = this.dataItem();
    console.log(object);
}
```

I find this result like this :

```
init {_events: {…}, _handlers: {…}, value: "BCC/0025", text: "BCC/0025", pieceDetails: init, …}
parent: ƒ ()
pieceDetails: init {_events: {…}, _handlers: {…}, client: init, trLivraison: "1", trFacture: "0", …}
rowsDetails: init(3) [init, init, init, type: ƒ, _events: {…}, parent: ƒ]
text: "BCC/0025"
uid: "12472ae6-0baa-4ae2-a78b-0a980d1c8d17"
value: "BCC/0025"
_events: {change: Array(1)}
_handlers: {pieceDetails: {…}, rowsDetails: {…}}
__proto__: init
```

So how can I recover only the selected object as if I recovered from a simple ajax response like this:

```
{pieceDetails: {…}, rowsDetails: Array(3), mtRpGlobal: 0}
pieceDetails: {client: {…}, trLivraison: "1", trFacture: "0", code: "BCC/0025", date: {…}, …}
rowsDetails: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

And another question what is the difference between
`__proto__: init` and `__proto__: Object`

Comment: That means it's not a plain object but rather an instance of a class whose constructor is named `init` (a horrible practice popularised by jQuery).

Comment: @Bergi But it's possible to cast init object to simple object type

Comment: That depends on what that `init` class is. You can of course simply take the values out of the instance and construct a new object of your desired shape with them, but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :)